# I need How to split this string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, split

`var faxNum = $("#txt_faxnum").val();`

> //Value : ""kekurt kekt809" <(732) 588-8300>"

I want to split between "< >". Example: Just I need to this section :  (732) 588-8300

How to split this string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
var String=faxNum.substring(str.lastIndexOf("<")+1,faxNum.lastIndexOf(">"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. it is working.